# I want to take a local file path, and then open this path

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

I am working on an application in which the user selects a file from the file manager of any type and then it is stored in an array and then this file is opened when needed, but the problem is that I tried and searched a lot and I did not succeed

This is what I wrote :
To get Path :

```
        final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1001;


        btnBrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "DEMO"),1001);

        }
    });


 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri currFileURI = data.getData();
                String path=currFileURI.getEncodedPath();
                arrCoursesPath.add(path);
                txtPath.setText(path);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

To Open File :

```
    private void openPath() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri mydir = Uri.parse("file:"+arrCoursesPath.get(0));
    intent.setDataAndType(mydir,"application/*");    // or use */*
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

When executed, the error is when opening the file and it tells me that the element does not exist

What is the solution, guys ?!

Comment: Have a look at my library - https://github.com/HBiSoft/PickiT

Comment: Thank you I actually did the experiment
but how do I return the path as String ?

pickiT.getPath(data.getData(), Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

Comment: have a look at the read me or the demo project. You have to implement the callback methods

Comment: For your ACTION_VIEW add intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, data.getData()); Dont mess around with paths and so.

Comment: I will try thank you very much

Comment: HB. Thank you my friend again The problem has been solved thanks to your library